# Android Studio tool pane / window layout (full window width)

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am wondering how i can setup my lower tool pane (terminal in this example) in AndroidStudio that it behaves like it does in the other IntelliJ based tools (like AppCode)

Here is a screen of the current Android Studio Layout

[image]

But i want the lower pane to look like it does in AppCode for example. (I mean the lower pane should be full window width instead the left pane full window height)

[image]

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Did you try `Window -> Restore Default Layout?` Shortcut `Shift + F12`

Comment: Does not change anything :/

Comment: Then you might have saved this view as default view (another option under Window menu)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default view of Android view is as you want it to be (Second screenshot in your question). Try to restore to the default layout

```
Window -> Restore Default Layout
```

Shortcut `Shift + F12`

(The above is on a Windows machine. Other operating systems will have a similar option inside Android Studio.)

**Update:** (If the above does not work)

Goto

```
Settings - > Appreance And Behavior -> Appearence

Uncheck the option "Widescreen Tool Window Layout"

Click Apply
```

It will give you the full width tool window layout. Tried and tested.

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/viewing-modes.html)

Comment: which version of Android Studio are you on?

Comment: Android Studio 1.5.1
Build #AI-141.2456560, built on December 1, 2015
JRE: 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833 x86_64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Apple Inc.